# Ruby Regex doesn't terminate

Tags: ruby, regex, string

So basically I wrote a webcrawler the other day and now I'm encountering the following problem:

Given the String `"https://abs.twimg.com/a/1429571790/img/t1/grey_header_web.jpg);"`

I can't match it against the regex 
`/^(https?:\/\/)?([\da-z\.-]+)\.([a-z\.]{2,6})([\/\w \.-]*)*\/?$/`

Basically, typing this in the IRB, there is no termination:

```
"https://abs.twimg.com/a/1429571790/img/t1/grey_header_web.jpg);" =~ /^(https?:\/\/)?([\da-z\.-]+)\.([a-z\.]{2,6})([\/\w \.-]*)*\/?$/
```

I suspect it's because of the semicolon, but how do I avoid this and why can't ruby do this?
Am I doing something wrong?

If it matters, I'm using ruby 2.0.0p481 (2014-05-08 revision 45883)

Comment: Use a possessive quantifier: `^(https?:\/\/)?([\da-z\.-]+)\.([a-z\.]{2,6})([\/\w \.-]*)*+\/?$`. Is that better? See http://rubular.com/r/ElcekEruyJ

Comment: Whoops. I wasn't aware that I'm wielding the Ruby "close as duplicate" hammer, so I need to put forth some explanation. While the linked question isn't strictly a duplicate, it explains the underlying problem: catastrophic backtracking due to nested quantifiers. In your case, removing the last `*` should solve the problem.

Comment: Works like a charm. Thanks a Million, stribizhef! If you want, write an answer so I can accept it ;)